# In VBA Excel when I copy one cell to another, if it is a date it is not copied, what do I do?

Tags: excel, vba, date

This is probably quite simple but I've googled and can't find an answer. I am also just learning VBA (I have done VB.NET etc. etc.)

If the cell the macro is trying to copy is a date I just get a number copied, e.g. 40352 from 23/06/2010

Here is a code snippet, any help most appreciated, thanks:

```
Sheet5.Range(Cells(rwStartNumber, currentColumn + 1).Address(False, False)) =
     Sheet5.Range(Cells(rwStartNumber, currentColumn).Address(False, False))
```

Obviously this is in two loops, but that's not where the problem is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following

```
With Selection
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End With
```

Let me know if it works for you,

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You see the number because that's [how Excel stores dates](http://excelwiki.com/excel-dates-and-times/how-excel-stores-dates-and-times/): you need to [change the format of your target cell to be Date](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1865519.php) and it will display properly.

Comment: I had an inkling it was something like that. Is there a way to copy the formatting along with the cell data? I've had a search and the Range().Select and then Selection.Copy, Selection.Paste method brings up application errors or somesuch (and I'm not even sure if that would copy the formatting anyway)

Comment: @Thomas King Take a look at PasteSpecial method with xlPasteFormats http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195818%28office.11%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the property NumberFormat from the source cell, e.g.:

```
'Following line copies the values...'
ws.Cells(curRow, curCol + 1) = ws.Cells(curRow, curCol)

'And this copies the formats...'
ws.Cells(curRow, curCol + 1).NumberFormat = ws.Cells(curRow, curCol).NumberFormat
```

(ws is a variable of the type Worksheet, you can assign it e.g. like this:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet5")
```

or you can just use ActiveSheet)